# Why Taylor series for $\sin$ about 0 does not converges uniformly to $\sin$ on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, uniform-convergence

I need to prove that the Taylor series for $f(x)=\sin(x)$ about 0,$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k$$ does not converges uniformly to $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464283/showing-a-series-is-not-uniformly-convergence?rq=1

Comment: In particular, $\sin x$ is bounded and its Taylor polynomials are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abstract: *Taylor series is a series of polynomial.*

Assume it converges uniformly to sin, then by definition of uniform converges, there is a polynomial with infinitely many zeros. Or alternatively, since every non-constant polynomial are unbounded on $\mathbb{R}$, but sin is definitely bounded on $\mathbb{R}$. So there is no series of polynomial converges uniformly to sin.There is a contradiction.

Therefore, the Taylor series of sin does not converges uniformly to 
sin on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Does intermediate value theorem help?